# Php, after change session.name, session ID will be changed everytime I load

Tags: php, session

I have a strange error regarding the session name and session id.

I have used `ini_set()` to change `session.name` from `PHPSESSID` to 'AAA'

Also `ini_set()` is set before `session_start()`

Tired to use `session_name()` instead, same result

After I do that, the `session_id()` will return different id whenever I load the page. After I change back, work fine again.

May I have help to solve this?

Thank you very much!!

Update Solution:

[Cannot change php session cookie name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005883/cannot-change-php-session-cookie-name)

Comment: Why not use session_name() ( http://us3.php.net/session_name ) instead? Also, are you sure you changed the session name 'before' you start the session?

Comment: @JaapMoolenaar, session_name() will have same result too.

Comment: I found the solution

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005883/cannot-change-php-session-cookie-name

Comment: Alright ( it should ). How are your cookies setup? ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php ) Are you perhaps changing domains between requests? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438335/php-session-losing-data-between-pages

Comment: Ah, great! scratch my last comment.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `$mySession = session_name("AAA");` where `$mySession` is the current session?